# Testing for empty fields in VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm making a fairly simple macro that adds a new record to a list. I'm trying to keep it from working when the fields are blank, so I've implemented a check for whether or not the input fields are empty. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
Sub AddRecord_Click()
    Dim itemName As String
    Dim itemPrice As Integer
    Dim nextRow As Integer
    Dim idNumber As Integer

    nextRow = Sheets("REVENUES").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    itemName = Range("A2").Value
    itemPrice = Range("B2").Value
    idNumber = (Range("A" & (nextRow - 1)).Value) + 1

    If Range("A2").Value <> "" And Range("B2").Value <> "" Then
        Range("A" & nextRow).Value = idNumber
        Range("B" & nextRow).Value = itemName
        Range("C" & nextRow).Value = itemPrice
        Range("D" & nextRow).Value = Date
        Range("A2").Value = ""
        Range("B2").Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is all of the data activity happening on "REVENUES"? If your are working on multiple sheets i could see that as being an issue since all the code references the active sheet by default.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using .Cells(iRow, iCol) instead of Range(R1C1) with this, just because it's a lot easier to loop and switch columns with variables instead of "A", "B", etc.

Comment: "Can't seem to get it to work" is such a broad complaint. Care to narrow it down? (I suspect @Dustin has nailed it though).

Comment: Have you considered using dropdown boxes for the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way of writing what you have above.  With more information about how this is set up,  I could edit and revise this.   Also, your itemPrice should be a double, not an Integer.

This is based off of your Original code.  But looking deeper into it. I'm not sure how you have the ID column being the same column as the Name?  I fixed it in the solution below, but you will have to see the layout of the sheet in the screenshot.

In this example, you input the Name in B2 and the Price in C2.  You could modify it.  My brain just had to write it that way.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub AddRecord_Click()
    Dim itemName As String
    Dim itemPrice As Double
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim idNumber As Integer

    nextRow = Sheets("REVENUES").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If Sheets("REVENUES").Range("C2").Value = "" Or Sheets("REVENUES").Range("B2").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please Complete Input Cells")
    Else
        itemName = Sheets("REVENUES").Range("B2").Value
        itemPrice = CDbl(Sheets("REVENUES").Range("C2").Value)
        idNumber = (Sheets("REVENUES").Range("A" & (nextRow - 1)).Value) + 1

        Sheets("REVENUES").Cells(nextRow, 1).Value = idNumber
        Sheets("REVENUES").Cells(nextRow, 2).Value = itemName
        Sheets("REVENUES").Cells(nextRow, 3).Value = itemPrice
        Sheets("REVENUES").Cells(nextRow, 4).Value = Now

        Sheets("REVENUES").Range("B2").Value = ""
        Sheets("REVENUES").Range("C2").Value = ""

    End If
End Sub
```

[image: MessageBox]

EDIT:  Updated Solution with working code.